# How can I configure Devel::SmallProf to work with mod_perl?

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I have the following version being installed:

```
Apache::SmallProf - 0.09 
Apache::Registry - 2.01
Devel::SmallProf - 2.02
```

And I try to add the following settings in my apache config file (/usr/local/apache_modperl/conf/httpd.conf):

```
<Perl>
    require Apache::DB;
    Apache::DB->init;
</Perl>

<Directory /home/website/www/cgi-m>
    SetHandler perl-script

    PerlSetVar Filter on
    PerlSetVar CleanLevel 5
    PerlAddVar CleanOption whitespace

    PerlHandler Apache::Registry
    PerlFixupHandler Apache::SmallProf

    Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

When I first run by request a CGI through web browser, here is the error message I get:

```
[doraemon] [modperl] [Mon Jun 22 07:20:39 2009] [error] /usr/local/apache_modperl//logs/smallprof does not exist: No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8/Apache/SmallProf.pm line 46.\n [failed] [Connection refused]
```

OK. At least I know smallprof is trying to run. Hence, I manually create directory /usr/local/apache_modperl/logs/smallprof and ensure it is writable by anyone.

I try again:

```
[doraemon] [modperl] Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x11a9ac78, Perl interpreter: 0x9e6ba80 at (null) line 236. [failed] [Connection refused]
[doraemon] [modperl] [Mon Jun 22 07:22:22 2009] [notice] child pid 10203 exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [success]
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might actually have an easier time with [Devel::NYTProf::Apache](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-2.10/lib/Devel/NYTProf/Apache.pm):

```
# in your Apache config file with mod_perl installed
PerlPassEnv NYTPROF
PerlModule Devel::NYTProf::Apache
```